# JavaScript set element attribute data return json data empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am a newbie JQuery/JavaScript user having a problem and cannot understand why my div data attribute is empty 
after saving/retrieving the DOM data. I need a little help if possible with examples to explaining what I am doing wrong.
I have spent a few hours on this with no light in sight.

```
    // HTML
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="mydiv" data-myval=""></div>
    </div>

    // JS file body

    function getSomeData(){
        var url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
        }).done(function(data) {
            //var myjson = data;
            var myjson = JSON.stringify(data);
            $("#mydiv").attr("myval", data);  // setter
        }, "json");
    }


    $(document).ready(function()
    { 
        getSomeData();

        // get json data from attr data-myval
        //var object = JSON.parse(myjson);
        var myjson = $("#mydiv").data();  //getter

        alert(myjson);  

        if(typeof object === 'undefined') 
        {
          alert('No data found!');

        }
        else
        {
            // do something
            var lat = object.lat;
            var lng = object.lon;

            // more codes
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous.  The data element will not be set by the time you perform the getter

Comment: Your getting the value before it's set by the AJAX request, secondly when the AJAX request is finished you're setting a plain attribute on your element to house the returned json response, not setting a data attribute, so $("mydiv").data() wouldn't return the correct value anyway.

Comment: What is the best work-around for this situation? Do I need to separate codes by putting the function <code>getSomeData </code> in a different file?

Comment: Use the promises to do your work

Answer (score 0):

*First*, it is important to understand that AJAX requests run asynchronously. This means that JavaScript will continue execution of your code while your browser is waiting for the response. To visualize:

```
JS execution  
|
|            getSomeData() runs, sends AJAX request to -------> server
|                  |                                               |
|                  V                                               |
|            var myjson = $("#mydiv").data(); //not yet set        |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  |
|                                                                  V
|           .done(function(data) {}); //executes upon response <--response
V
```

So if you want to retrieve the data in your `data-myval`, you can only do so after your AJAX call has finished. There is no point in getting this data immediately after you call `getSomeData()`. You could for instance get the data after the user clicks on something.

*Second*, you have to set the data attribute with the `.data()` function, not the `.attr()` function.

Example solution:

```
// HTML
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="mydiv" data-myval=""></div>
    </div>
    <button id="clicker">Click me!</button>
```

```
// JS file body

    function getSomeData(){
        var url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#mydiv").data("myval", data);  // setter
        }, "json");
    }


    $(document).ready(function()
    { 
    getSomeData();


    $("#clicker").click(function(e) {
        var data = $("#mydiv").data("myval");  //getter
        alert(data.exampleItem);
    });
```